# Access Query uses Form Inputs as Parameters - Runs manually, not through Form

Tags: sql, forms, parameters, ms-access-2010

I have a query that accepts input from a form. The query works as expected when I run it, manually typing in the form input values. However, when I run the query from the form, the query returns blank - no error, just blank.

I don't understand what's causing it - at it's most basic, the user is simply entering a Start and Stop date. I'm entering the data exactly the same, and made sure my form text box is formatted as a date.

Furthermore, when I run the form, I am not prompted for any values, so I know it's reading them accurately. This system works for several similar queries, but not this one.

**What I've tried**

- Changing the format of the text box to specify Short Date (which is how I type it)
- Visually confirming the values are making it from the form to the hidden staging area the query references - these values match what I manually enter into the prompts
- The query I'm runnning references another query; running the other one by itself only yields one set of "date" prompts, not two. So I created a seperate date input box for each to read off of, but to no avail

**Question: Does Access try and format (or not format) parameter input boxes differently than it would handle form references?**

Additional detail - when I run the query manually, it prompts me for the dates twice - I don't know why or it's pertinent, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Are you using the query as the data source when you load a recordset with the `OpenRecordset` method?

Comment: @HansUp The query references the user input like ">[Forms]![userForm]![Start Date]" - I'm not using OpenRecordset.

Comment: Quiet a few questions, @AaronContreras. Does thie Query feed off other Queries? Is the control's format set to Short/Long date? Can you **EDIT** your post to, show the Query and the code behind the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by tweaking my query in the designer - specifically by splitting up my expression into multiple pieces and writing the criteria in segments.

I'm not sure why this did the trick, but it at least got me where I needed to go.

Good luck to anyone else experiencing this!

Answer (score 0):

use instead Temporary variable in your Query for the specified dates.  After you select the dates from the Form, make sure that the values are assigned to the temporary variables and that you requery the record source of the form